# I need the MySQL query for merging Two databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

I have tried it a couple of different ways but nothing is working. I am a total newbie at this but need to merge a new `MySQL wordpress database` into an old one.

I am entering this into "Run SQL query/queries on database" field on one of the databases.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_database1 SELECT * FROM user_database1
```

Both databases are on the same domain.

Comment: Are you trying to merge databases or tables? `INSERT` operates on tables, not databases. Also, you have the same database as INTO and FROM, is that a typo?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_database1 values(SELECT IGNORE FROM user_database1)
```